# After my connection to SQL Server using stored procedure, I am getting an error on 'ExecuteNonQuery' why?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, sqlconnection

I open my `SqlConnection`, then use a foreach loop to collect the data and with my stored procedure. I use `Parameters.AddWithValue` to send the data into my stored procedure, but I keep get an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function spInsertLeafPickup has too many arguments specified.

Any reason why?

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE TYPE Templeafpickup AS TABLE 
   (
       ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
       Address NVARCHAR(50),
       SeasonType NVARCHAR(50),
       NextPickupdate NVARCHAR(10)
   )

CREATE PROCEDURE spInsertLeafPickup
     @Templeafpickup Templeafpickup READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO LeafPickup([ID], [Address], [SeasonType], [NextPickupdate])
        SELECT
            [ID], [Address], [SeasonType], [NextPickupdate]  
        FROM
            @Templeafpickup
END
```

C# class:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    con1.Open();

    foreach (DataRow dr1 in dt.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertLeafPickup", con1);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //Insert stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", dr1["PCOMBINED"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeasonType", dr1["PSSSTREET"]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NextPickupdate", dr1["ZST"]);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); <= Error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function spInsertLeafPickup has too many arguments specified.'
    }

    con1.Close();
}
```

Comment: You can define the command and parameters outside the foreach loop. Then just set the value of each of the parameters in the loop.

Comment: The error doesn't get any clearer that that.  How else are we suppose to explain it to you???  In your sp definition, you only have 1 parameter.  But you are passing 3  in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You are sending 3 parameters via c# code but you have declared 1 parameter only in stored procedure. Please check once how stored procedure is defined.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/160/sql-server-stored-procedure-tutorial/

```
   create proc spInsertLeafPickup
   @Address varchar, 
@SeasonType int,
@NextPickupdate date
   As 
   Begin 
   insert into LeafPickup([ID],[Address],[SeasonType],[NextPickupdate])
   Values(NEWID(),@Address,@SeasonType,@NextPickupdate]
   End
```

Comment: gaurav mujhi lagha all three declare kerne hai?

Comment: So if its just one being declared will it just be Address?

Comment: You have to define all 3 parameters in stored procedure and if you get value of ID based upon these 3 values from TempLeafPickup table then fetch it and use all these values in insert query or also if you can share the structure of TempLeafPickup to resolve the mystery of ID, then it will be clearer.

Comment: Let me Share it

Comment: Gaurav I have shared th TempLeafPick table

Comment: but just to let you know my official table is LeafPickup that is where I want to data to be stored

Comment: Edited my answer with stored procedure as per my understanding, phew a lot of work ! please mark as accepted answer if it clarifies. :)

Comment: NEWID() does not generate an INT. It is something like "CA9AB273-E975-41C1-8F90-2A6174435E1C"

Comment: @JBrooks Yeah just gave an idea if ID is GUID.

Comment: @AzibHaque Welcome my friend, please mark this as accepted answer, it will boost up my points :P

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use - as a parameter, it defaults to **1 character** in length .....

Answer (score 1):

If the table definition for LeafPickup has the ID as an INT and IDENTITY, something like:

```
Create Table dbo.LeafPickup 
   (
   ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL primary key,
   Address nvarchar(50),
   SeasonType nvarchar(50),
   NextPickupdate nvarchar(10)
   )
```

Then your stored proc would not insert the ID - it will be auto generated for you. So the stored proc would be:

```
create proc dbo.spInsertLeafPickup
   @Address nvarchar(50), 
   @SeasonType nvarchar(50),
   @NextPickupdate nvarchar(10)
   As 
   Begin 
      insert into LeafPickup(Address, SeasonType, NextPickupdate)
      Values(@Address, @SeasonType, @NextPickupdate]
   End
```

Comment: Be careful here. You have defined varchar as a parameter with no size defined, the default there is 1.

Comment: @SeanLange you are correct, I have updated my answer.